# More efficient way of highlighting selections?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have about 30 options that a user can select. When they click the option it opens/highlights a content/html box for that selection and hides the others (*similar to a picture lightbox but instead of thumbnails and main pic I need html*).

I've found this Jquery code example: http://jsfiddle.net/EhtrR/1238/

```
<img id="img1"/>
<img id="img2"/>
<img id="img3"/>
<img id="img4"/>

<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div id="div4">4</div>

$("#img1").on('click', function() {
   $("#div1").fadeIn();
   $("#div2,#div3,#div4").fadeOut();
});
$("#img2").on('click', function() {
   $("#div2").fadeIn();
   $("#div1,#div3,#div4").fadeOut();
});
$("#img3").on('click', function() {
   $("#div3").fadeIn();
   $("#div1,#div2,#div4").fadeOut();
});
$("#img4").on('click', function() {
   $("#div4").fadeIn();
   $("#div1,#div2,#div3").fadeOut();
});
```

(Please note the images are just example. These can be **div** boxes or **span**.)

but as I'll need 20-30 of these options I was wondering how I can make it more efficient or do you suggest another way? I noticed on Mobile touch taps the clicks were fairly slow with the Jquery.

Comment: The numbers in the ids are the same. Extract it, hide all divs, show the div with id `#div + <number>` -> done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To DRY and simplify the logic you could put each set of elements in containers, grouped by their behaviour. Then apply common classes to them and relate them on click by their indexes. Try this:

```js
let $contents = $('.content');

$('.trigger').on('click', e => {
  let $target = $contents.eq($(e.target).index()).fadeToggle();  
  $contents.not($target).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.content { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trigger-container">
  <img src="01.jpg" class="trigger" />
  <img src="02.jpg" class="trigger" />
  <img src="03.jpg" class="trigger" />
  <img src="04.jpg" class="trigger" />
</div>

<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content">1</div>
  <div class="content">2</div>
  <div class="content">3</div>
  <div class="content">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That is so much cleaner than referencing each number. I'm assuming the index is the order of the classes?

Comment: That's right, it's based on the order of elements within their parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let i=0;i<=4;i++){
   $("#img"+i).on('click', function() {
      $("#div"+i).fadeIn();

       for(var num=0; num<=4; num++)
       {
         if(num!=i)
         {
           $("#div"+num).fadeOut()
         }
       }  
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you test your answer before posting it?

Comment: I am sure this way.

Comment: Seriously. I added the comment for a reason... - Even with the fixed typo it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/o6ykzvs5/1/

Comment: Now with the second edit where you've replaced `var` with `let` (but not even in both loops)